# How can I make http calls inside a loop to be synchronous in dart flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can i make the entire foreach loop to be synchronous? I am not able to remoce "async" as http is being called inside the loop.

So there are 2 sets of http calls, the first http call gets the main data and then I am looping insde the main data's list to get the `venues_venue` field's id to call another api to obtain the child data, from the child data I am trying to push the `['title']['rendered']` back into the main data's list

Now the issue is, since the foreach loop is async, the final list is not including the `['title']['rendered']` field

```
List userArtworkVenuesList;
Future<String> _getUserArtworkWishList() async{

 //first http data retrieved
 var responseArtworksInWishList = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull(artworksApiBase+getArtworksApi));
 var convertedData = json.decode(responseArtworksInWishList.body);

 userArtworkVenuesList = convertedData;

 looping the above retrieved list to get the id of an item to call another http, then the retrieved item's data is appended to the parent's list
 countTheLoop = 0;
 convertedData.asMap().forEach((index,item) async{

   //print(item['custom_post_custom_fields']['venues_venue'][0]);

    var venueResponse = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull(specificVenueBase+item['custom_post_custom_fields']['venues_venue'][0]));
    var venueData = json.decode(venueResponse.body);

    // print(venueData);
    print('the index');
    print(index);
    print('the name of the venue is ');
    print(venueData[0]['title']['rendered']);


    convertedData[index]['venue_name'] = venueData[0]['title']['rendered'];


    countTheLoop++;



 });


  userArtworksList = convertedData; //this is where the problem is
  print(userArtworksList); //doesn't have the `venue_name` I see in the console the data is still being loaded

}
```

Just wondering If I can force the foreach loop to be synchronous?

Comment: if you are using `await http.get` it means that the next http call will be executed after the previous has finished and your loop will be executed in sync, or maybe i am missing something in your question?

Comment: @pskink I have updated my question for a better understanding :)

Comment: @pskink `await http.get` inside the loop will be in sync, but how about the entire foreach loop? since I have to specify `async` on the loop in order to have http calls inside, I want the loop itself to be in sync so that the codes after the loop is not executed till each item inside the loop is done

Comment: @pskink pls see the updated question (the last 2 lines) , at this point where I am printing `userArtworksList` it doesn't have the `venue_name` assigned yet. isn't the loop supposed to be completed first before it assigns `convertedData` to `userArtworksList` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an old-style for loop

Please compare:

```
import 'dart:async';

Future updateMap(map, k, v) {
    return new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      map[k] = v +1;
  });
}


void asyncForEach() {
  var map = {'a':1, 'b':2};
  map.forEach((k,v) async {
    await updateMap(map, k, v);
  });
  print(map);
}

Future asyncFor() async {
  var map = {'a':1, 'b':2};
  for (var mapEntry in map.entries) {
    await updateMap(map, mapEntry.key, mapEntry.value);
  };
  print(map);
}

void main() async {
  asyncForEach();
  await asyncFor();
}
```

Output

```
{a: 1, b: 2}  //Immediately
{a: 2, b: 3}  //After 4 seconds
```

Note that in the second version, each iteration is executed in sequence, which may or may not be what you want.
You may prefer to launch all the tasks, collect the futures, and use `Future.wait` to wait for a list of Futures.

Comment: thank you! `await Future` was the key here so that it waits for all the item's to be looped in the list :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Lesiak, was almost going this approach, here is how I fixed it! : I separated the forloop into a separate function using the await Future like this:

```
List userArtworkVenuesList;
List userArtworkVenuesListTemp; //assign main data for temporary untill loop is over

Future<String> _getUserArtworkWishList() async{

userArtworkVenuesListTemp = convertedData;
var cc = 0;
   await Future.forEach(userArtworkVenuesListTemp, (item) async {

      await getAllVenues(item,cc);
      cc++;
  });

 userArtworkVenuesList = convertedData; 
 print(userArtworksList); // now this prints `venue_name` perfect! :) 
}


getAndAppendAllVenuesToList(item,index) async{

 var venueResponse = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull(specificVenueBase+item['custom_post_custom_fields']['venues_venue'][0]));

  var venueData = json.decode(venueResponse.body);

  userArtworksListTemp[index]['venue_name'] = venueData[0]['title']['rendered'];
    // print( userArtworksListTemp[index]);
}
```